# EEE PC won't charge when in use

Tags: battery, asus-laptop, eee-pc

I just bought an Asus EEE PC 1015BX which runs Windows 7. My problem is that the battery doesn't charge when I'm using the computer. It doesn't discharge either, it just stays at the battery charge level where it was when I turned it on.

For instance, when I turn it on, plugged in to AC, at 22%, it will stay at 22% forever.
If I plug it in when it's off, it will charge to 100% without problem.

I'm often at a place when I don't have any AC available, so I really need it to charge while being used.

I've already looked in the BIOS, and even updated my BIOS to 0604 version, but it doesn't help.

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not for your type of computer but it does hit on the problem and has a [proposed solution](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/).

The steps he performed were as follows.

1. Disconnect AC
2. Shutdown
3. Remove battery
4. Connect AC
5. Startup
6. Under the Batteries category (Start--> type "device" --> Device Manager --> Battery), right-click all of the Microsoft ACPI
   Compliant Control Method Battery listings, and select Uninstall
   (it’s ok if you only have 1).
7. Shutdown
8. Disconnect AC
9. Insert battery
10. Connect AC
11. Startup

I would double check your battery settings etc. and see if anything differs between plugged in and not plugged in. Then if you feel comfortable read that article and give those steps a whirl.

Comment: @blue112 If that doesn't work maybe its something covered under warrenty? Just a thought...95% of the time its easier to fix yourself.

Comment: yeah it's covered but I would make me send the computer far away, and it would be painful not to have a PC for so many time.